# How to handle async Start() errors in TopShelf

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, topshelf

I have a TopShelf service that uses async code to connect to web services and other application servers.

If it's unable to initialize its connections on startup, the service should log some errors and gracefully stop.

I've had a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23791696/how-to-catch-exception-and-stop-topshelf-service) about stopping TopShelf when the start conditions aren't met. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28239617/531971) talks about using the TopShelf HostControl to stop the service.

However, that answer relies on the `ServiceConfigurator<T>.WhenStarted<T>(Func<T, HostControl, bool> start)` method.

I am currently configuring the TopShelf service in the standard way:

```
x.Service<MyService>(s =>
{
    s.ConstructUsing(() => new MyService());
    s.WhenStarted(s => s.Start());
    s.WhenStopped(s => s.Stop());
});
```

However my service's `Start()` method is actually `async`, defined like this:

```
public async void Start()
{
    await Init();
    while (!_canceller.Token.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        await Poll();
    }
}
```

This seems to work fine. But I use the await keyword in several places in the function. So, I can't simply change my `Start()` method to take a `HostControl` and return a `bool`, because I would have to return `Task<bool>` from an `async` method.

I'm currently allowing exceptions to bubble up from the Start() function so that TopShelf can see them and automatically stop the service when the exception bubbles up. However, the exceptions are then totally unhandled by my code, and I therefore end up with nasty unhandled exception error messages in the various logs I write to. Which I would prefer to replace with a nice error message and a clean service shut-down.

So, I have two questions:

1. Is there any problem with using an `async void Start()` method for TopShelf?
2. Is there a way to make it so that if `Init()` throws an exception, the exception details are gracefully logged and then the service stops, given that my service runs `async` code?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Firstly, `async void` is almost always incorrect, except in some truly fire-and-forget scenarios.  You want to change that to `async Task`.

Then sometimes you just have to use `.Wait()` at the border between sync and async code.  In this case you probably want to rename your current async `Start()` method to `StartAsync()` and add a `Start()` method that calls it:

```
public void Start()
{
    StartAsync().Wait();
}

public async Task StartAsync()
{
    await Init();
    while (!_canceller.Token.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        await Poll();
    }
}
```

However, you have another issue, in that TopShelf's `Start()` method is not a `"Run"()` method; i.e. you are supposed to return from that method as soon as your service is started, not remain there while the service runs.  Given you're already using async-await, I'd probably instead not call `Wait()` in `Start()`, but save the `Task` returned from `StartAsync()`, then when `Stop()` is called, signal your `Task` to stop using that existing `_canceller`, and *only then in `Stop()`* call `.Wait()`, leaving you with something like this:

```
private Task _serviceTask;

public void Start()
{
    Init().Wait();
    _serviceTask = ExecuteAsync();
}

public void Stop()
{
    _canceller.Cancel();
    _serviceTask.Wait();
}

public async Task ExecuteAsync()
{
    while (!_canceller.Token.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        await Poll();
    }
}
```

I should add that the way you had it, you probably kind-of get away things to an extent, in the sense that your async `Start()` method will return to TopShelf as soon as it hits the first `await`, but will continue executing.  If your `Stop()` method calls `_canceller.Cancel()` then your async `Start()` method will terminate next time `Poll()` is called.

However the above is cleaner, and you have to ability to wait until the last `Poll()` finishes executing, which you didn't before.  You will also be able to handle exceptions, as you mention.

**Edit**
I'd also move the `Init()` call into `Start()`, as above.

Comment: How do I make sure the `_serviceTask` returned by `ExecuteAsync()` actually starts, without awaiting it in the `Start()` method? I can't await it there, because that would require `Start()` to be async. In test code with a mock `Poll()` method based on `Task.Delay()`, when I call `_serviceTask.Start()`, an `InvalidOperationException` is thrown with the message `Start may not be called on a promise-style task.` If I don't await or start the Task it seems to remain in the `WaitingForActivation` state?

Comment: Never mind, my test code sucked. ExecuteAsync() returns a running Task, so I don't need to do anything special to start it. I'm not sure why the Task's status was `WaitingForActivation` rather than running, but the Task does actually run and eventually completes.

Comment: One problem with this is, if the ExecuteAsync throws a exception this will never be noticed?

Comment: @Peter as you probably know the exceptions thrown in `ExecuteAsync` will be waiting untill some one calls `_serviceTask.Result` or checks the `_serviceTask.Excetpions`