# where to put `await`?

Tags: c#, async-await

Here is one class with 1 method,

```
public class ApiService
{
    public async Task StartAsync()
    {
        await _webHost.StartAsync();
    }
}
```

Now trying to call above class/method like below,

```
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {

        HostFactory.Run(
        configuration =>
        {
            configuration.Service<ApiService>(
                service =>
                {
                    service.ConstructUsing(x => new ApiService());
                    service.WhenStarted(x => x.StartAsync());
                });

            configuration.RunAsLocalSystem();
        });
    }
```

If I'm putting `await` like this, it's giving error, where to put async/await here?

```
service.WhenStarted(x => await x.StartAsync());
```

Comment: Try to put `await` keyword outside lambda expression: `await HostFactory.Run(configuration => { configuration.Service<ApiService>(service => { service.WhenStarted(x => x.StartAsync()); }); ... });`.

Comment: Yes, getting error - 'TopshelfExitCode' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and no accessible extension method 'GetAwaiter' accepting a first argument of type 'TopshelfExitCode' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: I'm trying to call in `Topshelf` configuration

Comment: Seems like you can't. You will have to run it synchronously. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39656932/how-to-handle-async-start-errors-in-topshelf also https://github.com/Topshelf/Topshelf/issues/375

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know the signature for `WhenStarted()` and since I can't find in in the documentation this may or may not work. Generally if you need to `await` a call you also have to mark the call as `async`.

```
service.WhenStarted(async (x) => await x.StartAsync());
```

Comment: Why not `service.WhenStarted(x => x.StartAsync());`

Comment: `T` is not equal to `TaskT<T>` or `void` is not equal to `Task`.

Comment: I think `async (x) => await x.StartAsync()` just adds an extra wrapper for `x => x.StartAsync()`, they should both work.

Comment: It's pretty easy to test.  A method *must* return a task to use await.  If you don't call await on a async task, it returns a `Task` or `Task<T>` (hopefully not void).  [It can be easily tested](https://dotnetfiddle.net/9WqT9w).  I highly recommend reading Stephen Cleary's blog on async.  It doesn't add anything, the async source is propagated up the call stack.  This also can be tested, if each method was wrapped the results from any method would not be literally equal, but [they are](https://dotnetfiddle.net/OlF6lt).